# asp-for is not working with specified ViewComponent locations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm returning a folder location in a `ViewComponent`s `Invoke()` method to get round the suggested folder locations (and the enforced `Components/ViewComponentName/ViewName.*` location when you try to change `ViewLocationFormats.Add("/{0}.*")` in `Startup`

But because I'm doing this, the `asp-for` tags on my views don't work any more.

A simple example:

I hit the `Index` page via `Get` on my people controller

### PeopleController

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModels.VMPersonSummary vm = new ViewModels.VMPersonSummary();
    vm.Property = "HELLO";
    return View(vm);
}
```

This passes the `ViewModel` to the view:

### Index View

```
@model People.ViewModels.VMPersonSummary

<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(People.ViewComponents.PeopleSummary.Search), Model)
</div>
```

Model is passed fine to the `ViewComponent`:

### Search ViewComponent

```
namespace People.ViewComponents.PeopleSummary
{
    public class Search : ViewComponent
    {
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(VMPersonSummary vm)
        {
            return View("~/ViewComponents/PeopleSummary/Search.cshtml", vm);
        }
    }
}
```

And on the `View` (which is returned fine) the following works:

```
<p>Value = @Model.Property</p>
```

but things like:

```
<label asp-for="Property"></label>
<input asp-for="Property" class="form-control" />
```

Are just empty, null, nothing, non-existent.

I'm worried this is because I didn't set up the `ViewComponent` locations in the startup, but I don't want to because it's restricted to use, at least somewhere in the filepath, `Components/ViewComponentName/`

And I wanted my specific `ViewComponents/SpecifiedFolder/ViewName.*`

Any idea on how to wire the `asp-for` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems if you've moved your ViewComponent Views to a non-recommended location then you need to add

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

to the top of the file

ffs